# How to assert a type parameter is not "dynamic" in a const constructor in Dart?

Tags: dart

Suppose I have this very basic struct:

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  final T bar;

  const Foo(this.bar);
}
```

I would like to enforce the type specialization, that is prevent the instance to be created with `Foo(1)` for example (`Foo<int>(1)` should be used instead).

One way to do so it to use add an `assert` statement in the constructor initializer list to ensure `T != dynamic`:

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  final T bar;

  const Foo(this.bar) : assert(T != dynamic, "Can't create a Foo of dynamic type");
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem compatible with the `const` constructor as it raises an error: `Invalid constant value` for both `T` and `dynamic`.

Is there any workaround and why is `dynamic` considered as non-constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Once your object is instantiated, `T` is fixed.  Therefore you could just `assert` somewhere else in your class.  It'd be constructible but unusable.
2. Consider using [`strict_raw_types`](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/resources/type-system/strict-raw-types.md) instead.  Add:

   ```yaml
   analyzer:
     language:
       strict-raw-types: true
   ```

   to your `analysis_options.yaml` file to disallow `Foo(1)`. (Note that explicitly using `Foo<dynamic>(1)` would still be allowed.)